getDocs(collection(db, "products")) not returning any docs in Remix App Using Firebase and Shopify Hydrogen
Trying to implement a default Firestore DB into my Remix web application that integrates with Shopify Hydrogen, and the getDocs query getDocs(collection(db, "products")) returns a snapshot with no documents. I have followed the documentation almost verbatim. I know this is not a connection issue as the reads are going through to Firestore, and I get a querySnapshot with the relevant Firestore information.
When I log the querySnapshot however, it returns a snapshot with both 'docs' and 'oldDocs' properties with root objects of size: 0 (try catch didn't seem to offer any useful information either).

Config file:
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export default db;

Relevant Code:
import db from '~/firebase-config';
import {collection, getDocs, query} from 'firebase/firestore';
...

export async function loader(args) {
const criticalData = await loadCriticalData(args);

  return defer({...criticalData});
}

async function loadCriticalData({context, params, request}) {
  const {handle} = params; 
  const {storefront} = context;

  const products = []; // products array to store collection data

  if (!handle) {
    throw new Response(null, {status: 404});
  }

  const [{product}, variants, querySnapshot] = await Promise.all([
    context.storefront.query(PRODUCT_QUERY, {
      variables: {
        handle,
        selectedOptions: getSelectedProductOptions(request),
      },
    }),
    context.storefront.query(VARIANTS_QUERY, {
      variables: {handle: params.handle},
    }),
    getDocs(collection(db, 'products')),
  ]);

// organize products collection array
  console.log('querySnap:', JSON.stringify(querySnapshot));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    products.push(doc.data());
  });
  return {
    product,
    variants,
    products,
  };
}

Example log output of querySnapshot:
  "_firestore": {
    "app": { ... },
    "databaseId": { "projectId": "...", "database": "(default)" },
    "settings": { ... }
  },
  "_snapshot": {
    "query": { ... },
    "docs": { "keyedMap": { "root": { "size": 0 } }, "sortedSet": { "root": { "size": 0 } } },
    "oldDocs": { "keyedMap": { "root": { "size": 0 } }, "sortedSet": { "root": { "size": 0 } } },
    "docChanges": [],
    "mutatedKeys": { "data": { "root": { "size": 0 } } },
    "fromCache": true,
    "syncStateChanged": true,
    "excludesMetadataChanges": false,
    "hasCachedResults": false
  },
  "metadata": { "hasPendingWrites": false, "fromCache": true },
  "query": { "converter": null, "_query": { "path": { "segments": ["products"], "offset": 0, "len": 1 } } },
  "type": "collection",
  "firestore": { ... }
}

I have double checked that config is correct and that the products collection exists in Firestore with existing documents; I also ensured that Firestore security rules allow read/write access to the products collection (currently in test mode).
Expected to get a querySnapshot with documents in it, but again, when I log it I get 0 documents.
I'm really lost as to how to debug this further, especially since the query is so simple and logging doesn't seem to help. Maybe this might be a region issue (set to NA when I'm currently in South Korea), or an environment issue (something to do with Remix?).
Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong or if anyone has had a similar issue.

I don't see any documents in your products collection.  The screenshot shows a popup covering where the document list would appear.  Maybe you would like to improve the screenshot so that it actually shows the documents that you expect to return from the query.

Please edit your question and add a screenshot of your "products" collection. Please respond using @AlexMamo
